# Summing a column in Pandas Groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I want to group by column A, and sum over column C and return the results immediately into the dataframe. I know that I need to use groupby, and I know that I need to use sum, but I cannot figure out how to get these functions to interact seamlessly and in one line of code.

Have

```
    A    B      C
0   x   text    3
1   x   text    7
2   y   text    5
```

Want

```
    A    B      C    D
0   x   text    3    10
1   x   text    7    10
2   y   text    5    5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

call [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#transformation) on the `groubpy` to add the aggregated column back to the original df:

```
In [28]:
df['D'] = df.groupby('A')['C'].transform('sum')
df

Out[28]:
   A     B  C   D
0  x  text  3  10
1  x  text  7  10
2  y  text  5   5
```

`transform` returns a series with its index aligned to the original df so you can add it as a new column